# Incorrect syntax near the keyword LEFT

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, join

Hello I have a syntax error on this query in C# that I don't know what causes it, when I query this in Microsoft SQL server 2012 I just get data as supposed to, can anyone help me out :

```
        SqlConnection connectie = new SqlConnection("user id=;" +
           "password=;server=;" +
           "Trusted_Connection=false;" +
           "database=; ");

        SqlCommand statsDocenten = new SqlCommand("SELECT enquete_vraag as vraag,AVG(enquete_antwoord_radio) as gemiddelde_antwoord,docent,vak" +
        "FROM ENQUETE_ANTWOORD " +
        "LEFT JOIN KDV " +
        "ON ENQUETE_ANTWOORD.kdv_ID = KDV.kdv_ID " +
        "LEFT JOIN DOCENT " +
        "ON KDV.docent_ID = DOCENT.docent_ID " +
        "LEFT JOIN VAK " +
        "ON KDV.vak_ID = VAK.vak_ID " +
        "LEFT JOIN ENQUETE_VRAAG " +
        "ON ENQUETE_ANTWOORD.enquete_vraag_ID = ENQUETE_VRAAG.enquete_vraag_ID " +
        "WHERE DOCENT.docent_ID = " + docentid + " AND VAK.vak = " + vak + " AND ENQUETE_ANTWOORD.enquete_antwoord_radio != '' " +
        "GROUP BY enquete_vraag,enquete_antwoord_radio,docent,vak", connectie);
```

I have already checked out a bunch of questions in the "Questions that may already have your answer" area but I don't know which problem and answer affects my query.

Comment: You need a space after `vak` on the first line.

Comment: If you had simply printed out the string, you could have seen this yourself, since it would have shown `,vakFROM`.

Comment: In this case, it's quicker to debug than to post a question here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was simply a matter of a missing space.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a space on your first line between `vak` and `FROM`.

You should definitely parameterize your query (search for it and you'll find the "how" and "why"). Also, you'd have better luck using the @ symbol prior to your string (known as a [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)), and you can have multi-line strings without having to concatenate a bunch of them:

```
string sql = @"
SELECT enquete_vraag as vraag,AVG(enquete_antwoord_radio) as gemiddelde_antwoord,docent,vak
FROM ENQUETE_ANTWOORD
LEFT JOIN KDV ...etc...";
```

Comment: Thanks, I did totally not see that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
"...as gemiddelde_antwoord,docent,vak" + <----- you need a space here
    "FROM ENQUETE_ANTWOORD " +
...
```

Otherwise those lines read as

```
as gemiddelde_antwoord,docent,vakFROM ENQUETE_ANTWOORD
```